# Confirm message before deleted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I would like to have a confirm before deleting the file.My code without a confirm, which works like this

```
<form action="delete.php" method="get">
<table>
<?php 
    foreach ($files as $file) {
                   ?>
<tr>
        <td><?php echo $fajl['file_name'];?></td>
        <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $file['file_id'];?>"><img src="img/delete.png"/></a></td>
     </tr>
        <?php } ?> 
        </table>
    </form>
```

part of *delete.php*

```
...if(isset($_GET['id'])){
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $query = $pdo->prepare('DELETE FROM files WHERE file_id = ?');
   $query->bindValue(1, $id);
   $query->execute();
}
$files = $file->fetch_all();
...
```

and when I click on delete image file is deleted. it works great, but I would like to have a confirm before deleting the file. I tried to do it with *Zebra dialog* I add *class="delete"*

```
<a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $file['file_id'];?>"><img class="delete" src="img/delete.png"/></a>
```

and the next code

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
$(".delete").bind("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this);
    $.Zebra_Dialog("Do you want to delete this file?", {
        type: "question",
        title: "Are you sure?",
        buttons: ['Yes', 'No'],
        onClose: function (caption) {
            if (caption == 'Yes') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'delete.php',
                    data: {
                        id: $this.data('id'),
                        success: function(data){
            alert("File deleted");
        }
                    }
               })
            }
        }
    })
});
});
    </script>
```

but it doesn't work...
P.S.
Now I saw that *Zebra dialog* has an option

```
'buttons':  [
                {caption: 'Yes', callback: function() { alert('"Yes" was clicked')}},
                {caption: 'No'},
            ]
```

Is it possible that instead of

```
callback: function() { alert('"Yes" was clicked')}
```

I call

```
delete.php?id=<?php echo $file['file_id']
```

Comment: You should not delete things in response to GET requests.  Use a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `confirm('Message here')` which returns `true` or `false`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".delete").bind("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (window.confirm('Are you sure?'))
        {
            // .. ajax call ..
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

You have a syntax error inside your ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'delete.php',
    data: { id: $this.data('id') },
    success: function(data){
        alert("File deleted");
    }
});
```

In addition, there's no `$this.data('id')`, so inside your HTML:

```
<a data-id="<?= $file['file_id'] ?>" class="delete"><img src="img/delete.png"/></a>
```

Comment: Confirm and alert are both very ugly dialogs. Most people tend to avoid them because of their horrid look.

Comment: @Marcel: true, but they're functional and work, even if they're not pretty to look at.

Comment: They don't look *that* bad (and don't block all windows/tabs) in Firefox... (i.e. they don't look much worse than other modal dialogs)

Comment: @DavidThomas yes, but most clients/website owners care about that sort of thing :) I used to use them during development, but now `console.log` and asynchronous alternatives to alert/confirm are the way.

Comment: @MvanGeest The problem is exactly that. They look and work differently in different browsers.

Comment: Looking different in different browsers is certainly not always a disadvantage. That said, in this case, the industry standard is to create one's own modal dialog, so that's probably the best advice. See also http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/44609.